# Mysql: first match of each option

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

everybody,
I have in my Mysql 5.7 database the options that the customer can choose about the products I have on my website. The options are managed in four tables: options and options_name, options_group and options_group_name. So a combinatión of it:

```
SELECT
    ogn.option_group_id,
    ogn.option_group_name,
    o.option_id,
    ona.option_name
FROM options o
LEFT JOIN options_name ona ON ona.option_id = o.option_id 
LEFT JOIN option_group_name ogn ON ogn.option_group_id = o.option_group_id
```

shows:

```
option_group_id| option_group_name| option_id| option_name
4| size |1 | extra long
4| size |2| "extra long
4| size |3 | extra long
5| colour |4 | blue
5| colour |5 | green
5| colour |6 | "blue"
5| colour |7 | green
```

As you see it needs cleaning but until I can do it I need to create a query that gives me the first match of each option. In the example above: `1|extra long, 4|blue and 5|green`

With this query I can update the product table and then proceed to the cleaning of the options tables when I have the time.

I don't know very well how to crack the query, can you help me?

I've tried adding: `group by ona.option_name;`

But I get this error:

```
Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column ogn.option_group_id  which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by    0,00097 sec
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use FIRST_VALUE() function with proper partitioning and sorting. Do not forget to clear `option_name` from unnesessary symbols previously.

Comment: thanks but I am using mysql 5.7. I am going to add it to the post.

Comment: If so use a subquery which performs according clearing, grouping, and selects the least expression value which determines the ordering. Use the result of this subquery for output rows restriction (use another copy of source data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.option_group_id, t1.option_group_name, t1.option_id, t3.option_name
FROM test t1
JOIN (SELECT t2.option_group_id, 
             MIN(t2.option_id) option_id, 
             REPLACE(t2.option_name, '"', '') option_name
      FROM test t2
      GROUP BY 1,3) t3 ON t1.option_id = t3.option_id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c92a302aa5fcbfc6d99f03d35eddb52)